# JAX-RS application path not recognized in RESTEasy

Tags: java, path, jax-rs, resteasy, embedded-jetty

I'm using embedded Jetty 9.1.0.v20131115 with RESTEasy 3.0.7.Final. I have a JAX-RS application defined, which I know is working because all my singletons and classes are working. It looks like this:

```
@ApplicationPath("/foo/")
public class MyApplication extends Application {
```

I then have a resource like this:

```
@Path(value = "bar")
public interface BarResource {

  @GET
  @Path(value = "test")
  public String getTest();
```

So I try to issue a `GET` to `/foo/bar/test` and it fails. It only works when I change the resource annotation to the following:

```
@Path(value = "/foo/bar")
public interface BarResource {
```

This defeats the whole purpose of `@ApplicationPath("/foo/")`, allowing my resources to be defined relative to some base path. Why isn't RESTEasy picking up the `@ApplicationPath` annotation?

Comment: Is `MyApplication` picked up?

Comment: "... application ... which I know is working because all my singletons and classes are working."

Comment: Are you deploying to jetty via a WAR file?

Comment: "I'm using embedded Jetty...." No WAR files involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [api-doc points out](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/index.html):

> When published in a Servlet container, the value of the application
>   path may be overridden using a servlet-mapping element in the web.xml.

Seems like this is happening if you register the RestEasy HttpServletDispatcher like this:

```
ServletContextHandler servletHandler = new ServletContextHandler();
servletHandler.setInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application", "com.company.MyApplication");
servletHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(HttpServletDispatcher.class), "/*");
```

You could try to add this init-parameter:

```
servletHandler.setInitParameter("resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix", "/application-path");
```

Comment: Ah, I had read that but only now understand the full implications: the `@ApplicationPath` apparently is only relevant absent `web.xml`. But strangely, I am adding the servlet (in similar code to what you indicated) with a mapping of `/foo/*`. If the `servletHandler.addServlet(...)` is equivalent to "a servlet-mapping in the web.xml" then it should override to the very same value! Using `resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix` in conjunction with the programmatic servlet-mapping seems to work, thanks. I still don't understand why the extra property is needed, though, as I map the servlet correctly.

Comment: I also tried mapping to `/foo/*` and I also have no idea why this is not working...